# What causes dough made from coconut flour to not stick together?

Tags: baking, dough, flour, pizza, texture

I made a pizza dough with half wheat and half coconut flour and I noticed the dough wasn't as elastic and broke apart easier. Then I tried a dough with 100% coconut flour and it was essentially a crumbly mess until I added egg and even then it didn't have the typical texture of good pizza dough.

Why is this the case?

Comment: can you [edit] the question to add the complete recipe / method you used? That would make it easier to figure out what went wrong

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Gluten is what makes a dough stick together and have structure. Coconut flour has no gluten, so the resulting dough will be a crumbly mess. Intentionally gluten free recipes usually contain any number of special additives to compensate for the lack of gluten.

Comment: I doubt you could even use coconut flour when other GF flours are called for, because of its higher fat content and lower starch

Answer (score 8):

From [PrimalPal](https://www.primalpal.net/paleo-recipe-blog/148/blogdetail/148_10_tips_for_cooking_with_coconut_flour):

> Because it doesn't contain gluten like many flours, coconut flour doesn't stick together as well as traditional flour – this means you'll have to use extra eggs.

Also note that coconut flour is relatively high in fat, causing the different texture.

Comment: The high fat is a really important difference - it makes coconut flour much more suitable for use in things like pastry where you're adding a lot of fat to the mixture anyway.